# Python: How to change each element of a list in place

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list:

```
sentence = ['This','is','a','sentence']
```

I want to add a space in front of each element except the first one. Basically, the expected result is like this:

```
sentence = ['This', ' is', ' a', ' sentence']
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
for word in sentence[1:]:
    word = ' ' + word
```

However, this one does not change elements in `sentence` (Why?).

I can write some ugly code like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(sentence)):
    sentence[i] = ' ' + sentence[i]
```

I think this one will work but it's not a elegant way to do it...

What is the most Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Your existing solution is fine.  This question might be better on Code Review.

Comment: A big question is why you need to do the changes in-place.  Because of list comprehensions, it's generally much easier in Python to take an existing list, create a new list with the necessary transformations/filters applied to each element, and then have the variable point to the new list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it in-place:

```
In [206]: sentence = ['This','is','a','sentence']

In [207]: for i,word in enumerate(sentence[1:],1):
   .....:     sentence[i] = ' '+word
   .....:     

In [208]: sentence
Out[208]: ['This', ' is', ' a', ' sentence']
```

This handy one-liner does not do it in-place:

```
In [209]: sentence = ['This','is','a','sentence']

In [210]: sentence = [sentence[0]] + [' '+word for word in sentence[1:]]

In [211]: sentence
Out[211]: ['This', ' is', ' a', ' sentence']
```

Comment: I feel like the first solution is very similar to the one I have. The second one looks nice.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this doesn't *change* those elements, but re-assigns them, because strings are immutable in Python. The OP's first attempt would have worked just fine if `word` was a mutable type (say sub lists, and using `word.insert(0, ' ')`.

Comment: @LukasGraf: that is highly dependent on how `__add__` is implemented (which in the case of strings creates a new string). Reassigning still puts the pointer to the new string in same memory location within the list (underlying C array). Therefore, while the string isn't changed in place, but the list is. Since I didn't want to confuse OP with the semantics of string interning and peephole optimizations, I left out this discussion